# No such column: 'wagtailcore_page.latest_revision_id' post upgrade from wagtail 3 to wagtail 4.2.4

Tags: django, wagtail

I have recently upgraded my Wagtail version from v3 to v4.2.4
In this upgrade, the wagtailcore_page creates a new column latest_revision_id through one of its migrations under the library.

When I am trying to run my test cases, it is giving me an error with this column saying that it does not exist.

During deployment too I faced the same issue but running migrations in a specific order worked and issue was resolved.

During test cases, the internal test database is newly created and looks for that column before the migration that creates the column runs due to which this issue arise.

Please find below screenshot for reference.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXZlf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I assume you are running the tests on a CI/CD pipeline.

In my case the pipeline job was using an old cache (an old virtual-env with wagtail v3). Clearing the old caches and re-running the pipeline solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
Yes you are correct, I am running tests in CI/CD pipeline but it is picking up the latest versions 4.2.4 for wagtail.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @rucha What testing framework are you using? 
For 'pytest' I would change the invocation in the CI/CD pipeline to 'pipenv run pytest --migrations -svvv' to enable migrations and increase verbosity. Then check the logs that the new migration is actually being applied (I believe it is wagtailcore.0073_page_latest_revision).

Comment: What Antonio mentioned is true: I ran into this issue because I have a data migration on an application that sets up a website's basic Wagtail pages. In order to do that, it needs to import the Page model directly, and if wagtailcore migrations haven't migrated the database to a state that's consistent with how Page.objects.create works, then this happens.